# Android Studio cargar ReciclerView en Fragment

Tags: android

Quiero cargar un ReciclerView en un Fragment pero solo se muestra la platilla de xml y no me carga lo demás:

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Fragment_horizontal extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";

    //vars
    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();



    public Fragment_horizontal() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_h, container, false);

    }

    private void getImages(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initImageBitmaps: preparing bitmaps.");

        mImageUrls.add("https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4636/25316407448_de5fbf183d_o.jpg");
        mNames.add("Havasu Falls");

        mImageUrls.add("https://.jpg");
        mNames.add("Trondheim");

        mImageUrls.add("https://i..jpg");
        mNames.add("Portugal");

        mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mNames.add("Rocky Mountain National Park");


        mImageUrls.add("https://i..jpg");
        mNames.add("Mahahual");

        mImageUrls.add("https://i..jpg");
        mNames.add("Frozen Lake");


        mImageUrls.add("https://i..jpg");
        mNames.add("White Sands Desert");

        mImageUrls.add("https://i..jpg");
        mNames.add("Austrailia");

        mImageUrls.add("https://i..jpg");
        mNames.add("Washington");

        initRecyclerView();

    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview");

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), mNames, mImageUrls);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿En algún momento estas llamando al método `getImages()`? Si no lo estas invocando un buen momento es sobrescribiendo el onPostCreate del fragment. Si ya lo estas llamando estaría bien que pusieras el Layout también, a ver si hay algún error allí.

Comment: al colocar getImages me genera un error... te dejo el xml

Comment: al hacer el metodo en el activity si me carga las imagenes pero al hacerlo en fragment no me las carga    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getImages();

Comment: Es que si dejo todo en el maiactivity si funciona pero si lo programo en el fragment no me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Por que no inicializar el `RecyclerView` en el `onCreateView`? entiendo lo que haces luego con tu método `getImages()`, debes iniciar tu `RecyclerView`. Me parece que esta es la mejor manera de hacerlo:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_h, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),/*LISTA*/);

        recyclerViewPos.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view; 

    }
```

Para pasar la lista lo que puedes hacer es un método como este, que tiene como finalidad, crear llenar y devolver una lista llena, solo de implementar donde desees, en este caso, donde comente en el `Adapter`. Aquí lo hago creando un arreglo del objeto que este trabajando, dentro de el, lleno con los valores que necesite, y hago `return` a mi `ArrayList`, y por ultimo solo quedaría pasárselo al `adapter`, donde comente. Ejemplo:

```
public ArrayList<Objeto> buildArrayObject(){
        ArrayList<Objeto> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.add(new Objeto(/*VALORES QUE SEAN NECESARIOS*/);
        objects.add(new Objeto(/* MAS VALORES */);
        /*
         *
         *
         */
        return  objects;
}
```

Así lo pasas, como te comente:

```
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),buildArrayObject());
```

Allí el método que tienes de `getImages()`, puedes emplearlo para obtener nuevos datos, y si quieres pasárselo de nuevo al `RecyclerView` con la data actualizada según ese método, haces esto:

```
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),/*LISTA ACTUALIZADA SEGÚN MÉTODO */);

recyclerViewPos.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Es un ejemplo sencillo de como puedes lograrlo. Ya queda a tu criterio que datos quieres emplear en el `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Espero te funcione, cualquier cosa házmelo saber por acá, saludos

Comment: muchas gracias lo voy a implementar